# Why is $c_p$ higher than $c_v$?

Tags: thermodynamics

why is heat capacity at constant pressure higher than heat capacity at constant volume?
It is supposed to be this way, since if you increase $C_p$ in volume work is being done, in other case not. This is not clear to me either...

Comment: What do you mean "why"? You're apparently aware of the derivation.

Comment: I still don't feel it on an intuitive level...

Comment: Your second line is already intuitive explanation, that is Cp also counts extra work done. Namely there is a portion of input energy that is "wasted" as to become additional work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall two things...

- First that the 1st law is conservation of energy.
- Second that temperature is a non-decreasing function of internal energy.

So if we take two identical samples of gas and add the same heat $Q$ to each (increasing their internal energies), but allow one to do work $W$ on the surrounding while the other does none, then the sample doing the work experiences a smaller increase in internal energy and consequently a smaller increase in temperature.

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: But, if sample number one experiences a smaller increase in $T$, then his capability to save heat is worse in comparison to the other sample?

Comment: Think about the meaning of heat capacity: the amount of energy needed to achieve a fixed change in temperature. The constant pressure system got less change in temperature out of the same energy, meaning that it needs *more* energy to get the same change in temperature.

Comment: That's really *not* all there is to it, as some solids and liquids contract upon heating, but their constant-pressure heat capacity still exceeds their constant-volume heat capacity (this is always true) even though the atmosphere is doing work on them during the contraction.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't feel it on an intuitive level...

When a gas is heated at constant volume,all the heat supplied is used to increase the internal energy of the gas.(since the volume is constant the gas cannot expand so)

When a gas is heated at constant  pressure ,the gas expands.It does work against the external pressure .

The heat is used in two ways
1)partly to do work agaist external pressure.

2)partly to increase the internal energy.

so at constant pressure ,an additional amount of heat equivalent to work done is utilised.

Hence more amount of heat is required to increase the temperature of 1 mole of a gas at constant pressure than that at constant volume that is  $c_p$ higher than $c_v$